# Ingresar un elemento por posición en una pila y en una cola

Tags: c++, pilas, estructuras

1. Una función que saque el nodo de la posición N de la cola. Lo mismo para la pila.
   Tener en cuenta que los demás elementos deben quedar en el mismo orden. Para ello, en la pila desapile los nodos superiores en una pila auxiliar, elimine el nodo N y luego reapile los nodos de la pila auxiliar.
   Para la cola, desencole los nodos que siguen al nodo N, colocándolos en una pila temporal.
2. Una función que inserte un elemento en la posición N de la cola. Lo mismo para la pila.
   Tener en cuenta que los demás elementos deben quedar en el mismo orden. Igual que en el ejercicio anterior, lo que se pretende es desapilar o desencolar para acomodar el nuevo elemento y luego volver a colocar los demás.

El código:

```
struct nodo {
    int info;
    struct nodo *sig;
};

//variable global que apunta al primer nodo de la lista
struct nodo *raiz=NULL;

void insertar(int x)
{
    struct nodo *nuevo;
    nuevo = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    nuevo->info = x;
    if (raiz == NULL)
    {
        raiz = nuevo;
        nuevo->sig = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        nuevo->sig = raiz;
        raiz = nuevo;
    }
}

void imprimir()
{
    struct nodo *reco=raiz;
    if(raiz==NULL)
        printf("La pila está vacía.\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Impresion de Lista tipo pila...\n");
        while (reco!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%i ",reco->info);
            reco=reco->sig;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int extraer()
{
    if(raiz==NULL)
    {
        printf("La pila está vacía.\n");
        return -1;
   }
    else
    {
        int informacion = raiz->info;
        struct nodo *bor = raiz;
        raiz = raiz->sig;
        free(bor);
        return informacion;
    }
}

void liberar()
{
    struct nodo *reco = raiz;
    struct nodo *bor;
    if(raiz==NULL)
        printf("La pila está vacía.\n");
    else
    {
        while (reco != NULL)
        {
            bor = reco;
            reco = reco->sig;
            free(bor);
        }
        raiz=NULL;
    }
}


int cantidad()
{
    struct nodo *reco = raiz;
    int cant = 0;
    while (reco != NULL)
    {
        cant++;
        reco = reco->sig;
    }
    return cant;
}

int vacia()
{
    if (raiz == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}



int main()
{
    insertar(10);
    insertar(40);
    insertar(3);
    insertar(20);
    insertar(50);

    imprimir();
    printf("Extraemos un nodo de la pila: %i\n",extraer());
    imprimir();
    printf("La cantidad de nodos de la pila es: %i\n",cantidad());
    while (vacia() == 0)
    {
     printf("Extraemos un nodo de la pila: %i\n",extraer());
    }
//      extraer(); 
//      liberar();
    getch();
//  printf("%d",cantidad());
    imprimir();   
    getch();
    return 0;
}//ayuda
```

Comment: Fíjate que en la _pregunta_ no estás preguntando nada. ¿Qué dudas o problemas tienes? Me parece perfecto que nos pongas en contexto... pero aquí no vamos a analizar tu código para intentar adivinar dónde te estás atascando

Answer (score 0):

Lo que describes no me parece una mala lógica, pero podrias hacerlo más sencillo.
Podrías declarar en la estructura de la pila y la cola dos anclas que funjan de inicio y fin de la estructura.

```
typedef struct n{
    int data;
    struct n *next = nullptr;
}node;
typedef struct p{
    node *down = nullptr;
    node *top = nullptr;
    int size = 0;
}Stack;
```

De esta manera puedes hacer los procesos que deseas sin tener que instanciar más colas o pilas. Por ejemplo el método para agregar un elemento `n` en una posición `pos` en la pila:

```
void agregarEn(Stack *p, int numero, int pos){
    if(p){//no es nullptr
        if(pos <= p->size nad pos>=0){//la posición entra en el rango de elementos de la pila
            node *n = new node();
            n->data = numero;

            if(!pos){//insertar al inicio
                n->next = p->down;
                p->down = n;
            }
            else if(pos == p->size){//insertar al final
                p->top->next = n;
                p->top = n;
            }
            else{//insertar en una posición media
                node *temp = p->down;
                for(int i = 0;i<pos-1;i++)
                    temp = temp->next;
                n->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = n;
            }
            p->size++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: una pila a la que le añades elementos en el medio directamente no es una pila... este concepto es aplicable también para las colas... lo que le piden es trabajar con la lógica propia de las pilas y las colas... no saltarse esa arquitectura y tirar por la via rápida